# Is the infinitely-often version of Ladner's theorem known?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-intermediate, structural-complexity

We say two languages $\;\;\; L\hspace{.02 in},\hspace{-0.02 in}L' \: \subseteq \: \{\hspace{-0.02 in}0,\hspace{-0.05 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^* \;\;\;$ agree *infinitely-often* with each other

if and only if there are infinitely-many $n$ such that $\;\;\; L \cap \{\hspace{-0.02 in}0,\hspace{-0.05 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^n \: = \: L' \cap \{\hspace{-0.02 in}0,\hspace{-0.05 in}1\hspace{-0.03 in}\}^n \:\:\:\:$.

For a language $L$ let io-$L$ be 
the set of languages which agree infinitely-often with $L$.

Let io-P be 
the set of languages that agree infinitely-often with some language in P.

Let io-NPH be the infinitely-often version of NPH 
(NP-hard w.r.t. Cook reductions):

$L \in$ io-NPH iff for all $L' \in$ NP, some language in io-$L'$ is polynomial-time Turing reducible to $L$.

> Is ​ ​ ​ io-P does not contain NP ​ ​ ​ known to imply that ​ ​ ​ io-P $\cup$ io-NPH ​ does not contain NP ​ ​ ?

Comment: Note that the usual proof of Ladner's Theorem produces an NP-intermediate language that is in io-P. See also [Fortnow-Santhanam "Robust Simulations and Significant Separations"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2034)

Comment: @Kaveh: I don't see that io-NPH contains NP. For example, given an NP-intermediate language $L$, it seems unlikely that SAT is i.o. in $P^L$ (if $L$ is "sufficiently" intermediate, say, not in the high hierarchy). The latter isn't immediately obvious to me either, but as I say, seems unlikely.

Comment: @Kaveh : ​ ​ ​ What about the full language (all binary strings are in it) and the parity language (x is in it if and only if the number of 1s in x is odd)? ​ I claim that [those languages agree infinitely-often under the definition you edited in] and [under by my original question's definition and its current definition, it's _not_ the case that those languages agree infinitely often]. ​ Do you disagree with any of those claims? ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: I see, you are right.

Comment: Another point: The known proofs of Ladner's theorem essentially work using (countably many) conditions that are each satisfied after finitely many steps of the construction. In contrast, the condition to not be in io-P (or really any io class) is a countable union of *infinitary* conditions, so such a theorem would require a proof that was quite a bit different and stronger than the proofs (that I know of) of Ladner's theorem...